# Ubuntu 18.10 wifi not working at starbucks

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, dns, systemd-resolved

I had this problem with 18.04. Adding an entry to `/etc/hosts` as mentioned [in this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1766969).

In 18.10, that does not work.

I get an IP assigned via DHCP, but never get the login page.

```
NetworkManager[1026]: <info>  [1541282194.0196] dhcp4 (wlp61s0):   address 172.31.98.25
NetworkManager[1026]: <info>  [1541282194.0196] dhcp4 (wlp61s0):   plen 23 (255.255.254.0)
NetworkManager[1026]: <info>  [1541282194.0196] dhcp4 (wlp61s0):   gateway 172.31.98.1
NetworkManager[1026]: <info>  [1541282194.0196] dhcp4 (wlp61s0):   lease time 3600
NetworkManager[1026]: <info>  [1541282194.0196] dhcp4 (wlp61s0):   hostname 'myhost'
NetworkManager[1026]: <info>  [1541282194.0196] dhcp4 (wlp61s0):   nameserver '8.8.8.8'
NetworkManager[1026]: <info>  [1541282194.0196] dhcp4 (wlp61s0):   nameserver '8.8.4.4'
NetworkManager[1026]: <info>  [1541282194.0196] dhcp4 (wlp61s0):   domain name 'home'

systemd-resolved[841]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

Searching for the error didn't turn up anything helpful.

My phone connects to the same wifi just fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you configure a DNS server rather than using the one automatically provided via DHCP?

Comment: Yes, I configured DNS as outlined in Pauljohn32's post. That does not work. 

wlp61s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.31.98.25  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 172.31.99.255
        inet6 fe80::d6ae:780f:6cea:513f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether cc:3d:82:65:ca:8e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9991507  bytes 8410479191 (8.4 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6825759  bytes 2632085081 (2.6 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: This is a very unfriendly site. Can't edit comments. Sigh. 

Yes, I configured DNS as outlined in Pauljohn32's post. That does not work. 

It assigns an IP and sets the default route. I can't ping the router.

I'd include details, but these site won't let me.

Comment: netstat -rn 
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
    0.0.0.0         172.31.98.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp61s0
    169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 virbr0
    172.16.95.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vmnet8
    172.31.98.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 wlp61s0
    192.168.111.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vmnet1
    192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0

Comment: Sorry for the crappy formatting. There does not see to be any way for format comments.

Comment: Maybe I didn't wait long enough. I dissconnected and reconnected again. I could ping and resolve IPs, but could not access any web sites. Suddenly I got the splash page for starbucks. In summary, the changes I made were to edit the DNS server for "Google Starbucks" to manual configuration, using 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4. Sorry for the noise, hopefully this will help someone else persevere to a  solution :)